# Use REST API to get group SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a group on my site - I want users to be able to add and remove themselves from this group via a button on a page. What is the URL I should be using as a parameter to retrieve the group and the group membership? All the examples I've seen involve the 2013 interface, which returns a 404 when I pass it the parameter.

```
/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname(xxxx)
```

gives me a 404.

Unfortunately I can't wait to do this until we finish migrating to SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint is different for SP2010.  The URL below will return all SharePoint Groups on a site collection.

```
<SiteCollectionUrl>/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=substringof('SharePointGroup',ContentType) eq true
```

There's another way to achieve what you are trying to do with [SPServices](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/).

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: 'AddUserToGroup',
  groupName: '<Group Name Here>',
  userLoginName: '<User Login Name Here'>,
  completefunc: function(data,status){
    //Do something here like alert user that they've been added
  }
});
```

Likewise

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: 'RemoveUserFromoGroup',
  groupName: '<Group Name Here>',
  userLoginName: '<User Login Name Here'>,
  completefunc: function(data,status){
    //Do something here like alert user that they've been removed
  }
});
```

EDIT:
JSOM Add User ([Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185012(v%3Doffice.14)))

```
function addUserToSharePointGroup(){
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var groupCollection = ctx.get_web().get_siteGroups();
  var group = groupCollection.getById(<group ID number>); //Not sure if getByTitle or getByName is available.  Worth testing
  var userCreationInformation = new SP.UserCreationInformation();

  userCreationInformation.set_email('<email address>');
  userCreationInformation.set_loginName('DOMAIN\alias');
  userCreationInformation.set_title('<title here');

  var user = group.get_users().add(userCreationInformation);
  ctx.load(user);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){console.log(user.get_title() + " added.");},
    function(sender, args){console.error(args.get_message());}
  );
}
```

NOTE, if this is a single page application, you have to reference the following JS files before JSOM will work:
`/_layouts/1033/init.js`
`/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js`
`/_layouts/sp.core.js`
`/_layouts/sp.runtime.js`
`/_layouts/sp.js`

Comment: I already know the specific group I want to return - I don't want all groups on the site. And for (annoying) policy reasons, we're not using SPServices.

Comment: I'm guessing the policy is something like "No External Libraries."  Let me see if I can find you a better URL for specific groups.

Comment: It would depend on the users rights to add themselves to a group.  A better solution would be to use JSOM in a function to pull the user into the group.  no extra libraries will need to be loaded unless it's a single page app.

Comment: What's a better approach? The group that users will be adding themselves to has All Authenticated Users as an owner, (long story). The group they can add themselves to is to be used for email purposes only.

Comment: Using JSOM.  I'll add a snippet to my answer

Comment: The reason I'm trying to go the REST route is when I try the old-fashioned ExecuteQueryAsync route, I'm getting resource cant be found errors when I wrap it in an SOD.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded, and other errors when I don't.

Comment: It sounds like you have a single page app, or a custom aspx page created in designer that doesn't load the default javascript files.

Comment: File names are SP.js, SP.Core.js, and SP.Runtime.js.  see [This Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh372944(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Yes, it is a single-page app - the client wants a faux-ListServ.

Comment: Ok.  I finally found the full list of required files.  you have to bring in "/_layouts/1033/init.js", "/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js", "/_layouts/sp.core.js", "/_layouts/sp.runtime.js", and "/_layouts/sp.js" in that order preferably.  THEN you can run any code from Sharepoint's client side API, JSOM specifically.  [Reference](http://geekswithblogs.net/djacobus/archive/2014/06/06/156827.aspx)

Comment: Any luck getting it to work?

Comment: I did resolve my issue. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it :-)